How to format array initializer in VSCode?
This is what I've put in settings.json:
"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: Google, ColumnLimit: 210 }",

I want my array initializations not to break in the next line unless I use // at the end of a line or the line is going to continue beyond column 210. But In the following code I see that the elements in initialization of an array are splitted into the next line and don't continue in the current line, while it's much shorter than 210.
static struct table_view swl_lcore_table = {
    .head = "SWL Statistics / LCore",
    .head_color = HWHT,
    .num_column = 21,
    .title_row_span = 2,
    .row_span = 2,
    .total_row_span = 2,
    .titles[0] = {"Core",                                                      //
                  "TCP PPS",   "TCP PPS Cu.",   "TCP LRL",   "TCP LRL Cu.",    //
                  "UDP PPS",   "UDP PPS Cu.",   "UDP LRL",   "UDP LRL Cu.",    //
                  "ICMP PPS",  "ICMP PPS Cu.",  "ICMP LRL",  "ICMP LRL Cu.",   //
                  "o. p. PPS", "o. p. PPS Cu.", "o. p. LRL", "o. p. LRL Cu.",  // other protocols
                  "PPS",       "PPS Cu.",       "LRL",       "LRL Cu."},       // all protocols (total)
    .titles[1] = {"",
                  "White Listed",
                  "White Listed",
                  "White Listed",
                  "White Listed",  //
                  "White Listed",
                  "White Listed",
                  "White Listed",
                  "White Listed",  //
                  "White Listed",
                  "White Listed",
                  "White Listed",
                  "White Listed",  //
                  "White Listed",
                  "White Listed",
                  "White Listed",
                  "White Listed",  //
                  "White Listed",
                  "White Listed",
                  "White Listed",
                  "White Listed"},
    .size = {18,           //
             9,  9, 9, 9,  //
             9,  9, 9, 9,  //
             9,  9, 9, 9,  //
             9,  9, 9, 9,  //
             9,  9, 9, 9},
    .format = {TVCA_RIGHT,                                          //
               TVCA_MIDDLE, TVCA_MIDDLE, TVCA_MIDDLE, TVCA_MIDDLE,  //
               TVCA_MIDDLE, TVCA_MIDDLE, TVCA_MIDDLE, TVCA_MIDDLE,  //
               TVCA_MIDDLE, TVCA_MIDDLE, TVCA_MIDDLE, TVCA_MIDDLE,  //
               TVCA_MIDDLE, TVCA_MIDDLE, TVCA_MIDDLE, TVCA_MIDDLE,  //
               TVCA_MIDDLE, TVCA_MIDDLE, TVCA_MIDDLE, TVCA_MIDDLE},
    .color = BLU,
    .data_color[0] = HGRN,
    .data_color[1] = HCYN,
    .title_color = HWHT,
    .show_uptime = 1,
    .total_str[0] = "Total Requested",
    .total_str[1] = "Total White Listed",
    .total_col_span = 1,
    .total_color = BHWHT,
};

As you see this is happening for all members except titles[1]! Why?! Any idea?
